# How to select each class inside a div but separately using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to select an element of each class inside a div separately. I get all the `.community_node` elements at once, but I need each of them separately so I can put a space between them.

How would I change my code to do that?

```
$('.community_cluster').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('.community_node').text())
});
```

Comment: could you show us the markup? Do you actually need a space character as the content of the node or do you want just give some visual space between `.community_node` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the divs using `each()`, see below code

```
 $('.community_cluster').click(function() {
       var text = '';
       $(this).find('.community_node').each(function(){
          text += " " + $(this).text();
       });
       console.log(text);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a space between the values you could use `map()` to build an array of them all, then `join()` it by a space:

```
$('.community_cluster').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).find('.community_node').map(e => e.textContent).get().join(' ');
  console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: Hm doesn't work for me, probably because my `.community_node` class is within `<a href` tags?

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference in theory. It's impossible to say why this doesn't work for you without seeing the HTML